# Unabke to apply reciver object on a lmapda paramter to a high order function

Tags: kotlin

in the below code i am learning how ot use lampda function with object receiver and without. with function max1 when impl1 is passed as body block parameter the code works as expected.
However, with max2 and impl2 as code parameter, i could not use the reciever object style/notation...is it ever possible to apply the receiver object on a lmpda function as a prameter to a high order function?

the error eclipse generates is:

```
#unresolved reference error
```

please let me know if it ever possible to use the receiver object in side the body of a high order function

**code**:

```
    //lampda
    val impl1 : (String,String) -> Boolean =  {
        s1, s2 -> s1.length > s2.length
    }

    //lampda with a reciver object and scoping object
    val impl2 : String.(String) -> Boolean =  {
        s -> this.length > s.length
    }

    print(max1("1234", "12", impl1))
    print(max2("1234", "12", impl2))
}

fun max1 (s1: String, s2: String, c: (String, String) -> Boolean) : String {
    return "inside methods.....${ c(s1, s2) }" 
}

fun max2 (s1: String, s2: String, c: String.(String) -> Boolean) : String {
    return "inside methods ${ s1.impl2.s2 } "// #unresolved reference error
    return "inside methods ${ s1.c.s2 } "// #unresolved reference error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke your function with the receiver:

```
fun max2(s1: String, s2: String, c: String.(String) -> Boolean): String {
    return "inside methods ${s1.impl2(s2)} "//works
    return "inside methods ${s1.c(s2)} "//also works
}
```